# MVC Model not binding all fields from EF database first

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC application that is using EF (database first). On my edit, I noticed that all fields are populated from the database but ONE value (recording_id). I set a breakpoint in the controller and could see all the values returned but the recording_id is displaying as null. The value is populated in the database. The field is in the model and I am using the correct model. Any advice would be great.

View

```
@model IEnumerable<ScoreCard.Models.Car>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = Car Submission";
 }

<div class="jumbotron">

<h3>Car Submission</h3>
<hr class="style1" />

<div class='row'>
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "Submission")';return false;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Create Call Submission</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';return false;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</button>

    <br /><br />
    <div class='col-sm-12'>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>

                <th>
                    Car ID
                </th>

                <th>
                    Date
                </th>                                    
                <th>
                    Recording ID
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            @if (Model.Count() > 0)
             {



    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.car_id)
                </td>
                <td>                      
                    @String.Format("{0:d}", item.car_date)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.recording_id)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.id })
                </td>
            </tr>
    }
}
else
{
        <tr><td><h5><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> No Records Found</h5></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
}

        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
    public ActionResult Index()

    {

        return View(db.Cars.ToList());
    }
```

Model

```
public partial class Car
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string car_id { get; set; }
    public string recording_id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime car_date { get; set; }      
}
```

Comment: Can you provide table columns structure & how the model properties are populated from controller? Probably you're not setting `recording_id` or using different data type.

Comment: @user2448412  check datatype of recording_id is it proper.